# How do I find out a Twitter account is owned by an individual or Business organisation?

Tags: twitter

How do I find out a Twitter account is owned & maintained by an organisation or by an individual ?

**I want to know & filter the personal accounts.**

As i can differentiate through posts that each organisation tweets with a link to a particular product or service. But that sometime doesn't apply.

Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

There is no data in the API that identifies the account as belong to an organization, as opposed to belonging to an individual.

Comment: there has to be a distinction.

Comment: There is nothing in the API that identifies a user as an individual or an organization.

Comment: thanks! i will sort it out. & solution will be posted. :-)